# How to configure IPv6-enabled bridge?

Tags: configuration, bridge, ipv6

I'm looking for a valid configuration of an IPv6-enabled Tor Bridge. I have working IPv6-enabled relays, now I'd like to have a bridge (and not to loose IPv4 clients). I wonder if adding the following configuration will be enough:

```
BridgeRelay 1
ServerTransportPlugin obfs3,scramblesuit exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy managed
ServerTransportListenAddr scramblesuit [::]:52176
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs3 [::]:40872
```

I have verified that I connect to these ports using IPv4, but I am not sure if the Tor infrastructure will be able to cope with this configuration.

Comment: The Tor network doesn't know or care where your bridge listens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no IPv6-specific stuff in `torrc`, **but make sure to check all theese points** :

- You're running a system with IPv6 functionality enabled
- You have compiled **all** the pre-requisites of Tor and the Tor itself without IPv6-disabling flags
- You better run a local instance of [ISC Bind](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/) with IPv6 and IPv4 enabled, to make sure your DNS resolving won't be glitchy.